# Math problem help: Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, rbf-network

I am solving this problem from Bishop's 1995 book on Neural Networks:

In a multi-layer perceptron a hidden unit has a constant activation for input vectors which lie on a hyperplanar surface in input space given by $w^Tx + w_0 = const.$, while for a radial basis function network with basis functions given by the equation below, a hidden unit has a constant activation on a hyperspherical surface defined by $\|x - \mu\|^{2} = const.$. Show that, for suitable choices of the parameters, these surfaces coincide if the input vectors are normalized to unit length, so that $\|x\| = 1$.

The basis functions for the RBF network are of the form,
\begin{equation} \label{eu_eqn}
\phi_j = exp\left(-\frac{\|x - \mu_j\|^2}{2\sigma_j^2}\right)
\end{equation}

On the surface, this problem seems quite straightforward to solve. However, I am stuck in the beginning itself, probably because of the language used to express the problem. How is it possible for a sphere and plane to coincide? What am I missing? Would appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: The $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ constraint implies $x^\top x = 1$. Can you write out $\lVert x - \mu \rVert^2$ in a form that involves $x^\top x$?